# Using an MVC Model as a filter in the repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a details view that is typed to IEnumerable. The view with a bunch of drop downs that let you add filters to the list of records rendered.

All these dropdowns correspond to properties on the MVC model:

```
public class Record
{
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string LineOfBusiness{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'm using my model as my dto to shuffle data between my controller and my repo. Since all my drop down filters represent the model properties, I pass my model to a repo retrieval method, check its properties and filter based on its values? In other words:

```
 public IEnumerable<TradeSpendRecord> Get(TradeSpendRecord record)
    {
        IQueryable<tblTradeSpend> query = _context.tblRecords;


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(record.CustomerName))
            query = query.Where(x => x.CustomerNumber == record.CustomerNumber);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(record.LineOfBusiness))
            query = query.Where(r => r.LOB == record.LineOfBusiness);
```

***SNIP***

Hope this isn't too subjective, but I'm wondering if anyone has any input about whether this is a good/bad practice. I haven't seen a whole lot of examples of dynamic filtering like I need to do, and am looking for some guidance.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: This ties the mvc project to the dal which isn't ideal, i would opt for using parameters or an entities project where entities that are used used both in the dal and the mvc project are kept.  these can form the interfaces between the two layers

Comment: I actually make a habit of breaking out my Models into a separate project, and I as I said, I tend to use them as DTO's to move data between layers, and use ViewModels in my MVC project to provide specific data to a view.

Comment: Nothing wrong is here as soon as it's exactly what you need. In your case you query only by one property, but not by combination of them. What if you want to search by customer name and line of business simultaneously? But your code will search only by line of business.

Comment: @Kate That's not strictly true. The code provided applies a 'waterfall' technique where the result set is whittled down by applying one filter after another.

Comment: @AntP Yes, but only if you do search between query changes. But I can't see any code between them.

Comment: @Kate No, the second filter is applied on the new instance of `query` provided by the previous filter, **not** on the original object. If both properties have values, the `query` object is filtered first by `ContactNumber` and then the **result** of that query is queried again by `LOB`. Note the assignment `query = ` on the first filter.

Comment: Oh, now I can see. The "query" name confused me because it's not about query conditions but about result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing what I think you're doing, I'm not sure this is the best way of doing it.

Keep your 'Models' in your MVC/presentation layer (whether this is one physical assembly or not) dedicated to your presentation layer. The only things that should be touching them are your Views and your Controllers. You don't want what should be independent entities to be so tightly coupled to your View Models.

I'd suggest creating a separate `TradeSpendFilter` class, which, at its simplest, exposes the filterable properties of your domain entity (likely more than any given View Model). You'd then pass this into your "filtering service" or whatever it may be. This also means you can extend your filtering functionality independent of both your domain models and your MVC app. For example, if you suddenly want to filter multiple objects, you can simply change...

```
public class TradeSpendFilter
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

...to...

```
public class TradeSpendFilter
{
    public IEnumerable<string> CustomerNames { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

... without causing all sorts of problems for your MVC app.

Additionally, it will also mean you can make use of your filtering functionality elsewhere, without tying **further** components to your MVC app and ending up in a bootstrapped mess.

Comment: I agree, I began adding things to the model that didn't make sense for the model to have, and it became pretty obvious that I was violating the principle of single responsibility.